# BASH variable containing space only

Tags: bash, variables, space, double-quotes

I cannot figure out how to pass a 'space' (or more) as a variable.

```
MyVar=" "
echo $MyVar
```

returns nothing...

It doesn't seem to work like I hope, my goal is to make a random length string of spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash
while (( 1 ))
do
n=$[RANDOM%80]
x=0
sl=""
space="-"
while (( $n != 0 ))
do
sl=$sl$space
n=$(($n-1))
done
echo "$sl  #     #"
sleep 0.3
echo "$sl   #   #"
sleep 0.3
echo "$sl  #######"
sleep 0.3
echo "$sl ## ### ##"
sleep 0.3
echo "$sl###########"
sleep 0.3
echo "$sl# #     # #"
sleep 0.3
echo "$sl# #     # #"
sleep 0.3
echo "$sl   ## ##"
sleep 0.3
echo "$sl"
sleep 0.3
done
```

I would like the variable space to con taint a space, not a dash and report it to sl.
Is that even possible?

Comment: use quotes: `echo "$MyVar"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ever, you need double quotes around the value.

```
echo "$myVar"
```